# Is there a Clang mingw cross compiler for Linux

Tags: linux, mingw, llvm, clang, cross-compiling

In Linux, and specifically on Debian or Ubuntu, there are pre-packaged Mingw cross compilers which can generate Windows EXEs.

But is there a similar cross compiler using Clang instead of GCC? (Or instructions on how to build such a beast.)

Comment: Clang+llvm is not a complete toolchain anyway, you'll still need cross binutils and parts of gcc (namely, runtime library and headers). You can use an unmodified Clang with such a toolchain, it is already a cross-compiler by design.

Comment: clang is always a cross compiler.

Comment: @dwelch, please, elaborate.

Comment: the llvm compiler(s) compile to targe independent bytecode.  compiler is finished.  then optimizer or whatever, then if you are not executing jit, then you convert to assembler or directly to machine code for the target.  The standard pre-built binaries and/or default build includes all the targets.  So if you have an llvm install then you likely already have the tools you need to compile to (asm or object) for any of the targets llmv supports.

Comment: with gcc you have to build each compiler for a specific target processor and target operating system/platform.  For each variation you have to build/install a separate toolchain.

Comment: Ah, this I did not know, very interesting, thanks. @dwelch

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've written a tool with which you can compile easily with clang for windows on linux. Check out: https://github.com/tpoechtrager/wclang.